# Is there a way to remove the triangle that Chrome adds when using the <details> tag?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm using the `<details>` tag. And my code looks like this:

```
<details>
    <summary> Click me </summary>
    <p>Showing content</p>
</details>
```

In Firefox, it runs exactly as I expect. No triangles. Nothing. Just the text clickable content:
[How it looks like in Firefox](http://prntscr.com/p906rj)

But, on the other hand, Chrome adds a triangle which looks like this:
[How it looks like in Chrome](http://prntscr.com/p906in)

How can I remove that triangle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
details > summary {
  list-style: none;
}
details > summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}
```

It worked in my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nhscgwbf/